# how can I create a dll from a simple python code that could be call in VBA

Tags: python, vba, dll, py2exe

I know this is a a very large question but I'll try to make it as simple as possible.

Assuming that my `example.py` only holds the following code:

```
def xsum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

How could I encapsulate this into a dll that would be callable without actually having python installed on the end-user computer. My goal is to use it in VBA.

I looked at py2exe that creates a .exe but I can't find a solution for a dll. any help would be appreciated. I use python 3.6

Comment: You need to compile it to some COM type library. I'm not familiar with Python but I wouldn't think it was quite made for that. Or, you make the VBA code `Shell`-execute the .py script and somehow grab the return value.

Comment: seems like a weird question, but why not just create a VBA function.

Answer (score 2):

Cython (http:cython.org) produces C code from python sources. This generated can be compiled into a dll and called from VBA

Read the section "Using Cython Declarations from C" in the documentation

```
http://www.google.com/search?q="Using+Cython+Declarations+from+C"+site:cython.org
```